# Convert my WPF project to MVVM with Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, mvvm

I am new to coding in C# for that reason i made some mistakes when i started with my project. Meaning that all of my code is done in the forms (connecting to the database, doing select statements and upcoming update/insert/delete). Secondly most of my code is repetitive. I have several forms that are almost doing the same (the only difference is doing selects on different tables) as shown in the code.

This is from the form called Character:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Dark_Heresy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Character.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Character : Window
    {
        public Character()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void character_name_loader(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource= localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=Mypass;";
            string Query = "SELECT Name_ FROM dark_heresy.character_";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string charactername = myReader.GetString("Name_");
                    cb_CharacterName.Items.Add(charactername);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void cb_CharacterName_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = MyPass;";
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM dark_heresy.character_ WHERE Name_='" + cb_CharacterName.Text + "' ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string career = myReader.GetString("Class");
                    string world = myReader.GetString("World_Type");
                    string strength = myReader.GetInt32("Str").ToString();
                    string weaponskill = myReader.GetInt32("WS").ToString();
                    string ballisticskill = myReader.GetInt32("BS").ToString();
                    string fellowship = myReader.GetInt32("Fel").ToString();
                    string perception = myReader.GetInt32("Per").ToString();
                    string intelligence = myReader.GetInt32("Int_").ToString();
                    string agility = myReader.GetInt32("Agi").ToString();
                    string willpower = myReader.GetInt32("WP").ToString();
                    string toughness = myReader.GetInt32("Tough").ToString();


                    TextCareer.Text = career;
                    TextWorld.Text = world;
                    TextStrength.Text = strength;
                    TextWeaponskill.Text = weaponskill;
                    TextBallisticskill.Text = ballisticskill;
                    TextFellowship.Text = fellowship;
                    TextPerception.Text = perception;
                    TextIntelligence.Text = intelligence;
                    TextAgility.Text = agility;
                    TextWillpower.Text = willpower;
                    TextToughness.Text = toughness;

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void cb_Talent_NameDropDownOpen(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource= localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=MyPass;";
            string Query = "SELECT Talent_Name FROM dark_heresy.learned_talents WHERE Character_Name='" + cb_CharacterName.Text + "' ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string talent_name = myReader.GetString("Talent_Name");
                    Talent_Name.Items.Add(talent_name);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void cb_Talent_Name_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = MyPass;";
            string Query = "SElECT learned_talents.Talent_Name , talents.Description FROM dark_heresy.learned_talents, dark_heresy.talents WHERE learned_talents.Talent_Name = talents.TalentName AND learned_talents.Character_Name = '" + cb_CharacterName.Text + "';";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                Talent_Name.Items.Clear();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string talents_description = myReader.GetString("Description");

                    Talents_Description.Text = talents_description;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void Skill_Name_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource= localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=MyPass;";
            string Query = "SELECT Skill_Name FROM dark_heresy.learned_skills WHERE Character_Name='" + cb_CharacterName.Text + "' ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string skill_name = myReader.GetString("Skill_Name");
                    Skill_Name.Items.Add(skill_name);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            }

        }

        private void Skill_Name_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = MyPass;";
            string Query = "SElECT learned_skills.Skill_Name , skills.Descriptor FROM dark_heresy.learned_skills, dark_heresy.skills WHERE learned_skills.Skill_Name = skills.SkillName AND learned_skills.Character_Name = '" + cb_CharacterName.Text + "';";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                Skill_Name.Items.Clear();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string skills_description = myReader.GetString("Descriptor");

                    Skill_Description.Text = skills_description;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            }

        }



    }
}
```

A form called Talents:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Dark_Heresy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Talents.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Talents : Window
    {
        public Talents()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cb_loader(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource= localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=MyPass;";
            string Query = "SELECT TalentName FROM dark_heresy.talents";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string talentname = myReader.GetString("TalentName");
                    cb_Talents.Items.Add(talentname);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            }

        }

        private void cb_Talent_DropDownClosed_(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = MyPass;";
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM dark_heresy.talents WHERE TalentName='" + cb_Talents.Text + "' ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                    string description = myReader.GetString("Description");
                    string strength = myReader.GetInt32("R_Str").ToString();
                    string weaponskill = myReader.GetInt32("R_WS").ToString();
                    string ballisticskill = myReader.GetInt32("R_BS").ToString();
                    string fellowship = myReader.GetInt32("R_Fel").ToString();
                    string perception = myReader.GetInt32("R_Per").ToString();
                    string intelligence = myReader.GetInt32("R_Int").ToString();
                    string agility = myReader.GetInt32("R_Agi").ToString();
                    string willpower = myReader.GetInt32("R_WP").ToString();
                    string toughness = myReader.GetInt32("R_Tough").ToString();


                    TextDescription.Text = description;
                    TextStrength.Text = strength;
                    TextWeaponskill.Text = weaponskill;
                    TextBallisticskill.Text = ballisticskill;
                    TextFellowship.Text = fellowship;
                    TextPerception.Text = perception;
                    TextIntelligence.Text = intelligence;
                    TextAgility.Text = agility;
                    TextWillpower.Text = willpower;
                    TextToughness.Text = toughness;



                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have found out that it is required of me to do some business logic in my project. That led me to MVVM, which means my project is completely done wrong.

At the moment the only refence i have is to mysql.dll

I have read/seen tutorials on MVVM, however i have some question.

1. If i use the MVVM pattern would my database connections with SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE be stored in the ViewModel (business logic)? or would it be a part of the model?
2. Can anyone explain to me how i can change the current code so it can be used from model to ViewModel to View? If possible with an example.
3. In what form should the Model, ViewModel be in? WPF, interface, class, class library etc.
4. Does anyone have some useful links that might help me with this, specially when its combined with MySQL database that is a locahost.

Comment: OMG.. my eyes... Use Entity Framework, please.

Comment: @HighCore Ill have a look into Entity Framework, but as i said, i am new to programing C#.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Stack Overflow is a Q&A resource, not a help/discussion forum. It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers, not a place to ask open-ended questions seeking broad overviews, tutorials, introductory info, links, advice, opinions, or general pointers about getting started. Please read the [Tour] page and the following advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll tackle your questions in order:

1. No, they would be in the Model. Think of moving everything related to the Database into a layer of it's own - I suggest you look up a pattern called Repository and how it works (segregation of storage implementation from underlying storage technology via an interface).
2. You will need to make that judgement as you know what the code is doing. I suggest you read the Prism Library documentation on structuring applications, specifically section 4 on Modular Application Development - this should give you a great start on how real applications are structured. Don't worry about the detail specific to Prism look at how Views, ViewModels and Repositories are segregated into functional areas. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479(v=pandp.40).aspx
3. View is WPF XAML, ViewModel and Model should be C# classes typically.
4. See inline text above for the Prism Library documentation.

Also Prism works great as a set of class libraries to reference for the basis of an MVVM framework, even if you don't do the full Module Bootstrap Composite Application route. Plenty of classes utilising best practices for WPF development in there. It's a great source of information for a novice, but take time to understand the concepts.

**Update:** "Would you combine MVVM with a Repository?"

Okay, in typical commercial programming, you structure applications into 3 distinct layers of logic - Presentation, Business Logic and Data. Repository will typically sit in the Data Layer of an application. Business Logic typically encapsulates a service layer where the majority of the "real" business logic sits (and would be considered part of the Model from an MVVM perspective). Presentation is where MVVM sits, specifically the VM and Views.

Each layer will keep/have access to a reference to objects within the next layer, i.e. VM will have a reference to the Model/Business Logic layer, Business Logic will have a reference to the Data/Repository layer. VM would not typically have a reference directly to the Data layer as this breaks the layered architecture and could lead to complications.

In some instances (where you mix technologies for example e.g. TIBCO services for Business Logic layer), you won't even work on all layers of an application, but only one. This is where DB Specialist Developers come in, for example, especially in high performance systems where specialised queries are required to meet performance requirements in Data Warehouse systems.

Comment: One little quest, is it possible then to combine Repository with the MVVM pattern? or is it a patter for it self?